# How to debug a slow PySpark application

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

There may be an obvious answer to this, but I couldn't find any after a lot of googling.

In a typical program, I'd normally add log messages to time different parts of the code and find out where the bottleneck is. With Spark/PySpark, however, transformations are evaluated lazily, which means most of the code is executed in almost constant time (not a function of the dataset's size at least) until an action is called at the end.

So how would one go about timing individual transformations and perhaps making some parts of the code more efficient by doing things differently where necessary and possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spark UI to see the execution plan of your jobs and time of each phase of them. Then you can optimize your operations using that statistics. Here is a very good presentation about monitoring Spark Apps using Spark UI https://youtu.be/mVP9sZ6K__Y (Spark Sumiit Europe 2016, by Jacek Laskowski)

Answer (score 0):

Any job troubleshooting should have the below steps.
Step 1: Gather data about the issue
Step 2: Check the environment
Step 3: Examine the log files
Step 4: Check cluster and instance health
Step 5: Review configuration settings
Step 6: Examine input data

From the Hadoop Admin perspective, Spark long-running job basic troubleshooting. Go to RM > Application ID.

```
a) Check for AM & Non-AM Preempted. This can happen if more that required memory is assigned either to driver or executors which can get preempted for a high priority job/YARN queue.

b) Click on AppMaster url. Review Environment variables.

c) Check Jobs section, review Event timeline. Check if executors are getting started immediately after driver or taking time.

d) If Driver process is taking time, see if collect()/ collectAsList() is running on driver as these method tends to take time as they retrieve all the elements of the RDD/DataFrame/Dataset (from all nodes) to the driver node.

e)  If no issue in event timeline, go to the incomplete task > stages and check Shuffle Read Size/Records for any Data Skewness issue.

f) If all tasks are complete and still Spark job is running, then go to Executor page > Driver process thread dump > Search for driver. And lookout for operation the driver is working on. Below will be NameNode operation method we can see there (if any).
*getFileInfo()
getFileList()
rename()
merge()
getblockLocation()
commit()*
```